# Store parsed string on array to another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is my experimental code going to work/behave like my working code assuming the `HTML, CSS`, and prior `JS` work?

If not, why? Furthermore, what should I do to create an loop-array style version of my **code**?

Experimental code:

```
var currentAccount = [];
var fieldList = ["firstName","lastName","age","gender"];

for (var i = 0; i < fieldList.length; i++) {
    JSON.parse(fieldList[i]) = document.getElementById(fieldList[i]).value;
    currentAccount.push(JSON.parse(fieldList[i]));
}
```

Working code:

```
var currentAccount = [];
var firstName, lastName, age, gender;

firstName = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
lastName = document.getElementById("lastName").value;
age = document.getElementById("age").value;
gender = document.getElementById("gender").value;

currentAccount = [firstName, lastName, age, gender];
```

Answer (score 1):

> what should I do to create an loop-array style version of my code?

Something like this

```
var fieldIds = [ "firstName", "lastName", "age", "gender" ];
var currentAccount = fieldIds.map( function( fieldId ){
  return document.getElementById( fieldId ).value;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use `JSON.parse()` in you experimental code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < fieldList.length; i++) {
    var fieldVal = document.getElementById(fieldList[i]).value;
    currentAccount.push(fieldVal);
}
```

Comment: is it okay to have string variable name?

Comment: doesn't make sense modifying `fieldList[i]`

Comment: I update my answer to store field value in a temp variable instead of `fieldList[i]`. It's less confusing this way.

Comment: @TeokanDuranDemircan String is *value* of variable, not name. It is OK.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick solution using **ES6** and another way of doing **document.getElementById**. Hope it helps!

```
var $ = function( id ) { return document.getElementById( id ); };
var fieldIds = [ "firstName", "lastName", "age", "gender" ];
var currentAccount = fieldIds.map((fieldId) =>{
    return $(fieldId).value;
});
```